# Disable Future Date in Datepicker of Materialize frame work

Tags: datepicker, materialize

Here I am Using Date Picker of materialize frame work. Can anyone Please tell me how can i Disable Future Date from Current Date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 1.0 alpha version you can do you can specify [`maxDate`](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html) in the options field when initializing the datepicker:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.datepicker');
var instance = M.Datepicker.init(elem, {
    maxDate: new Date()
});

// Or with jQuery

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    maxDate: new Date(),
  });
});
```

The other version `v0.100.2` does not seem to have the [`maxDate`](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker) option.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code to your script:

```
max: new Date()
```